# Desmos slider function

Tags: desmos

Is there any way to keep all iterates for a slider value? Say I set n to run from 0 to 10 and I want x^n to show for each n. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can make a list going from 0 to n. This can be done by going to  a math line and typing b=[0... n]. This means b is a list of all integer values from 0 to n. Then you can say y=x^b. This should show x^1, x^2, x^3, all the way until x^10.